# Getting one error "Status Message: Invalid DPV: Channel Member ID " while creating subscriber in Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

While I am trying to create one subscriber to exact target I am getting the following error

> Status Message: Invalid DPV: Channel Member ID.

I used the below code:

```
CreateOptions createOptions = new CreateOptions();
SaveOption saveOption = new SaveOption();
saveOption.SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateAdd;
saveOption.PropertyName = "*";
createOptions.SaveOptions = new SaveOption[] { saveOption };

string requestID = string.Empty;
string status = string.Empty;

// Call the Create method on the Subscriber object
CreateResult[] cResults = client.Create(createOptions, new APIObject[] { sub }, out requestID, out status);
```

I am using  the Enterprise version of ExactTarget and  passing EmailAddress and FullName for creating the subscriber.

How to pass the ChannelMemberID through API to create one subsciber?

Comment: The issue was solved by adding ChannelMemberID through attribute.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer to your question, and checking it as answered.  Thanks!